# Pie chart slice - center of mass

Tags: javascript, math, highcharts, pie-chart

Using Highcharts, I'm trying to position rectangular elements above the "center-of-mass" of a pie chart slice.

I have the formula/algorithm for finding the center of the slice:

```
shapeArgs = Chart.series[0].points[sliceIndex].shapeArgs,
ang       = (shapeArgs.end - shapeArgs.start) / 2 + shapeArgs.start,
posX      = cX + shapeArgs.r/2 * Math.cos(ang),
posY      = cY + shapeArgs.r/2 * Math.sin(ang)
```

This finds the center of the slice based on the start & end angles, and the radius of the chart - represented by the black circle in the image below.  What I'm wanting is some way to find the center of the biggest rectangle that'll fit in the slice - represented by the green circle below (which I just eye-balled).  My reasoning is that an element positioned over the center-of-mass of the slice will fit better in the slice than something positioned at the exact center.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My rudimentary fix has been to reduce the factor by which the radius is reduced:

```
posX = cX + shapeArgs.r/1.3 * Math.cos(ang)
```

Which seems to work fairly well, but I'm wondering if there's a better way. Does anyone know the math for this?

**Edit:**

Screenshot of the result of tweaking the factor: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBH5p.png
Screenshot of the result of doing the Wikipedia math:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlGcS.png

Comment: It looks like a rather complicated problem in general case. Maybe you can reduce slices to be triangles which the solution seems to be simpler (find rectangle inscribed in a triangle). Also, brute force solution (checking the rects for all points along the slice and find the best fit) might be fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_centroids), the distance of the center of mass of a circular sector from the center is (2r * sin(a)) / (3 * a). I would find the `posX` and `posY` like this:

```
var dist = (2 * shapeArgs.r * Math.sin(ang)) / (3 * ang);
posX = cX + dist * Math.cos(ang);
posY = cY + dist * Math.sin(ang);
```

Comment: Thanks for the link - I didn't know what terms to search for.  Your code doesn't seem to work though.  I've updated the question with screenshots.  I admit I'm at a loss for how the trigonometry fits into the formula.

Comment: I understand how the trigonometry fits in now - but I'm still not sure why the result is so wonky.

Comment: Let's check the math: for sector with full angle 60 degrees, half-angle is 30 degrees = Pi/6. `dist = 2 * r * sin(Pi/6)/(3* Pi/6) = r * 2/Pi ~ 0.63 * r` But your second picture for "minor" sector shows vary small dist.